# How to implement Asynchronous application in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

So let me start with making the requirement pretty clear

1. I am creating a Java Server side application which has a couple of REST APIs. Now I want to collect stats and do some logging when the API is invoked via HTTP
2. Now logging and collecting/persisting stats can slow down the API call so I want this to happen asynchronously so API execution can go ahead.
3. So what solution would be best for this? I want to make sure that no data is lost and also the solution can scale with load. I thought of Akka framework but not sure it will meet my requirement. Creating simple threads to do the job might not scale. Is there any standard Java solution/pattern for this?

Comment: Too broad... read: https://technology.amis.nl/2009/02/19/asynchronous-processing-in-java-applications-leveraging-those-multi-cores/

Comment: First, this sounds a lot like premature optimization, as network overhead is likely to be a lot more of an issue than your logging. However, if it really is a problem, then Spring's `@Async` aspect support is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Implement a Thread pool with fixed number of threads(whatever is optimum)
- create custom objects that has all the details required w.
- have a Queue that can hold these custom objects
- Whenever API is called, create these objects and place them in Queue
- Threads should wait on the queue, if empty, dequeue these Tasks(custom objects), do the logging asyncronously.
- After the job is done, dont kill these threads. have a while() loop inside the thread, so that it can wait again on the queue to dequeue another task and perform it.